# How to create BalancingDispatcher using Akka in Java?

Tags: java, akka, akka-cluster, akka-dispatcher

I want to scale my application UP and DOWN depending on no of requests from users for this i want to share the same mailbox with all the presently running actors. I think Balancing Dispatcher will solve my problem as per his work stealing algorithm. But I am not able to figure out how to do it. I am new to akka framework. Some code samples about this will be really helpful. I have few questions regarding this,

```
1. How to lookup currently running ActorSystem ?
2. How to create actors on currently running remote ActorSystem ?
3. How to create BalancedDispatcher ?
4. How to share same instance of BalancedDispatcher ?
5. How exactly scalling UP and DOWN in akka works ?
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With scaling up and down, do you mean adding/removing virtual machines?

Instead of working to have those nodes share a mailbox, if possible I'd recommend just distributing the traffic over those (otherwise independent) nodes.

Is that possible? If not, why not?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion i changed my approach for this thing and now i am using clustering for this. But still i am interested to know whether in Akka can multiple actor share same mailbox ?